# Is there a way to reference a COM dll in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, dll, com

I am trying to automate a task on win10 desktop in a software called AxisVM, which luckily has a good COM interface.
My problem is that my current employer does not allow any programming languages to be installed on their PCs, so I am trying to re-implement a short, but functioning python script in PowerShell.

If I was working in e.g. C# then I could reference the interop dll in my project to be able to work with the constants and data types required by AxisVM.

Is there way to have that in PowerShell too?
I need to pass by reference the following struct when I call a function:

```
RAccelerationValues = (
double avX  // acceleration in local x direction [m/s2]
double avY  // acceleration in local y direction [m/s2]
double avZ  // acceleration in local z direction [m/s2]
double avXX // angular acceleration about  local x direction [rad/s2]
double avYY // angular acceleration about local y direction [rad/s2]
double avZZ // angular acceleration about local z direction [rad/s2]
double avR  // resultant acceleration [m/s2]
double avRR // resultant angular acceleration [rad/s2] )
```

I guess this is in a way similar to that if I was automating Excel and was connecting to Excel by `$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application`, would there be a way to use the xl??? constants in PowerShell that are otherwise defined?

**EDIT 1**
This is what I could write using a lot of resources from the internet:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\AxisVM_X5\Interop.AxisVM.FW4.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.dll"

$Assem =@(
        "C:\AxisVM_X5\Interop.AxisVM.FW4.dll",
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.dll"
         )

$Source = @"
using System;
using ax = AxisVM;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ax.AxisVMApplication axApp = new ax.AxisVMApplication();

            while (((ax.IAxisVMApplication)axApp).Loaded == ax.ELongBoolean.lbFalse)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            axApp.Visible = ax.ELongBoolean.lbTrue; // AxisVM starts hidden, so make it visible
            axApp.CloseOnLastReleased = ax.ELongBoolean.lbFalse; // Do not close AxisVM after this code
            axApp.AskCloseOnLastReleased = ax.ELongBoolean.lbTrue; // Ask whether close AxisVM after this code
            axApp.AskSaveOnLastReleased = ax.ELongBoolean.lbTrue;
            axApp.ApplicationClose = ax.EApplicationClose.acEnableNoWarning;

            ax.AxisVMModel axModel = axApp.Models.Item[1];

            axModel.LoadFromFile("C:\\Users\\x\\Documents\\_AXIS_TESZT\\tesztgerenda.axs");

            ax.AxisVMAcceleration axResAcc = axModel.Results.Acceleration;

            axResAcc.AnalysisType = ax.EAnalysisType.atDynamic;
            ax.RAccelerationValues resout = new ax.RAccelerationValues();
            string lcNAme;

            int num_of_timesteps = axModel.Results.TimeStepCount[ax.EAnalysisType.atDynamic, 1];


            Console.WriteLine(num_of_timesteps);

            axResAcc.LoadCaseId = 2;
            axResAcc.TimeStep = 1;
            axResAcc.NodalAccelerationByLoadCaseId(5, ref resout, out lcNAme);

            Console.WriteLine(lcNAme);
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp

[ConsoleApp1.Program]::Main()
```

...too bad I will never be able to use it because of the restrictions I have of running power shell scripts

Comment: `New-Object -ComObject ...` would be the way to do it, but you need to know the ProgID of the AxisVM assembly. If you show how you would attach the AxisVM assembly to your C# program, it might allow someone a bit more skilled in C# than I am to translate it to PowerShell.

Comment: I'll be following answers to see if there is a way to import constants and data structures into PowerShell. I don't know of a way. If you have Excel, have you considered using VBA to solve your problem? With it, you'll at least be able to import the constants and other typelib information into the VBA code.